# Streaming stdout from remote shell call

Tags: ssh, grep, remote-access

I have a read-only remote filesystem that stores logs.

I use ssh -t to run grep queries on these logs. Sometimes, the queries can take too long and cause the ssh to timeout.

Is there some way to stream the stdout back and keep ssh connection alive?

Example command:

```
ssh -t my-host.com "cd /path/to/my/folder ; find ./ -name '*' -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -P8 zgrep -B 5 -H 'My search string'" > search_result.txt
```

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code for connecting to the remote site and running these grep commands.

Comment: I've added the code thanks

Comment: What you need to do is set the SSH idle timeout. This causes SSH to send a null packet after the specified idle time, which will keep the connection alive. The method to do that depends on your SSH client.  Google "ssh timeout" or tell us what SSH client you are using for more information.